# Getting java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException, even i implemend serializable

Tags: java, object, serialization

```
public static void addToFile(LinkedList<Carowners> carowner)
{
    try
    {
    File file = new File(filename);
        FileOutputStream fout= new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        out.writeObject(carowner);
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hi this is my code.I am getting following error when i am object serialization.I implemented serializable, for the classes.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: 

Billing.Person
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.<init>(Carownerslist.java:42)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.main(Carownerslist.java:253)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Billing.Person
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.addToFile(Carownerslist.java:242)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.addCompany(Carownerslist.java:160)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.main(Carownerslist.java:285)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Billing.Carownerslist.addCompany(Carownerslist.java:149)
    at Billing.Carownerslist.main(Carownerslist.java:278)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What is in this line? `Billing.Carownerslist.addCompany(Carownerslist.java:149)`

Comment: @donfuxx Ihas parameters of type string.

Comment: I would like to take a look at your `addCompany` method because there an NPE is thrown

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Billing.Person. The class Carowners must be containing an instance of Billing.Person, which is not serializable.

Comment: @maress and before that is an NPE

Comment: @donfuxx public boolean addCompany(String name,String address,String vat)
    {
       Company p =new Company(name, address, vat);
       for (Carowners cown :carowners)
       {
           if(cown instanceof Company)
           {
               if(((Company)cown).vat.equals(vat))
                     {
                         return false;
                           
                     }
           }
       }
       carowners.add(p);
       addToFile(carowners);
       return true;
    }

Comment: @gowthamganguri Can you post your main method here. There seems to be two exceptions here, NPE and then serialization

Comment: @maress  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Carownerslist col = new Carownerslist();
        if( col.addCompany("asdf", "qwert", "123"))
       {
           System.out.println("Company added");
       }
        if(col.addcarToCompany("123", "sdfg", 1990, "123"))
        {
            System.out.println("car added");
        }
        if( col.addCompany("asdf", "qwert", "456"))
       {
           System.out.println("2 Company added");
       }
    }

Comment: @gowthamganguri is this the complete error trace? NPE must be occurring at the first call to addCompany (which since it does not end the program, you are catching it somewhere) and then serialization exception occurs at the second call to addCompany, which you must be trying to serialize after. those two exceptions are different. You may post all the relevant code in order to see whats the problem

Comment: @maress,@donfuxx.. Thank you.. i took care of null pointer exception. File was written with exceptions when i run first time .and it is being read everytime  not initializing the arraylist. It got rectified  now...

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in the stream. You have to recreate the stream now that you've made the class Serializable.

Comment: it worked for me so I up-voted the comment